# Which PayPal API for eBay Orders Shipping Address and PayPal Transaction Fee

Tags: php, paypal

I've a web application where user can authenticate their ebay account to access the CRM, this part is working fine.

However, I want to display Shipping Address from PayPal with PayPal Transaction Fees.

I tried contacting PayPal, they suggest use of Orders API or GetShippingAddresses.

Now due to lots of information at developer.paypal.com I am not sure which type of API will work? Adaptive, Rest, NVP/SOAP, SDK.

Ideally, I want the process to be smooth just like with eBay, like user will login with their PayPal to allow access to shipping & transaction fee data.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The AdaptivePayments APIs are no longer being approved for new live apps, so I'm not sure who referred you to that, but that was not a good recommendation (unless you already have a live Adaptive Payments app running, by chance.)

I'm a little confused about whether you're referring to details about transactions, or just in general..??  The fee would be per transaction I assume, but then it sounds like you want to just display available shipping addresses linked to the account in general..??

You've got lots of options for various ways to handle this.

- [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) - This will send a real-time POST of transaction data to your application for processing when they hit your PayPal account.  This could be a payment, a refund, a customer dispute, etc.  You can automate procedures accordingly based on the transaction, and you could store the shipping address and fee associated with these transactions based on the IPN data.
- [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) + [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) - Transaction Search will help find specific transaction IDs if you don't already have one, and GetTransactionDetails will pull all details including shipping address and PayPal fee.
- eBay [GetItemTransactions](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetItemTransactions.html) - Since you already have eBay hooked up, look at GetItemTransactions.  This pulls payment details for the eBay sale, which includes the PayPal transaction ID, fee, and shipping address.

There are actually more options as well, but I think one of those should take care of you.  I'd probably go with the last one since you already have eBay APIs hooked up.

Comment: eBay GetItemTransactions returns Final Value Fee & eBay's Shipping Address but do not return Fee & Shipping Address from Paypal.

Comment: @AhmedMemon Look at TransactionArray.Transaction.ExternalTransaction.  This includes FeeOrCreditAmount, which would be the PayPal fee.  eBay's FVF comes back in TransactionArray.Transaction.FinalValueFee.

Comment: I thought I remembered getting the shipping address from eBay as well in my previous projects.  It's been a while, though.  Are you sure the TransactionArray.Transaction.Buyer.BuyerInfo.ShippingAddress does not match PayPal when PayPal was used for purchase?

Comment: Here's an article they have on integrating PayPal with eBay apps:  https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/PayPal-witheBay.html   I skimmed it and it looks similar to what I outlined in my answer, but you might be able to find some extra info about shipping address in there if you research it.